# Se puede asignar a un elemento html mas de una clase css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Yo tenia entendido que a un elemento html no se le podia asignar mas de una clase css.
Pero aprendiendo JavaScript, el metodo `.classList` me ha generado la siguiente duda:
Si ese metodo nos devuelve una coleccion de las clases del elemento, que utilidad tiene, dando por hecho que solo va a poder devolver una coleccion con una sola clase, ya que el elemento HTML no va a tener nada mas.
Habia pensado que podria incluir tambien las pseudoclases, pero al mostrarlo en consola he comprobado que la coleccion solo contenia la clase y no las pseudoclases.

He llegado a la conclusión de que `.classList` es un método para elementos del DOM por lo que supongo que estara orientado mas a elementos mas generales como puede ser el document.

Una pequeña aclaracion me vendria muy bien.

Comment: Sí es posible asignar más de una clase a cualquier elemento HTML.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primero veamos qué dice [el estándar](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#classes):

> When specified on HTML elements, the class attribute must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the element belongs to.

**Traducción:**

> Cuando se especifica en elementos HTML, el atributo `class` debe tener un valor que es un conjunto de elementos separados por espacios representando las distintas clases a las que elemento pertenece.

Puedes asignar todas las clases que quieras a un elemento. Las clases sirven para aplicar propiedades o para agrupar elementos, pero un elemento puede ser parte de varias clases.

Un ejemplo sencillo: podemos crear un tablero de ajedrez con 64 divs (en el ejemplo no he puesto tantos para no hacer el código muy largo). Cada div pertenecerá a la clase celda, que define el tamaño y cómo desplegarse, pero el color vendrá dado por las clases negra y blanca:

```css
.chessboard {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
.black { 
  background-color: black;
}
.white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.cell {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="chessboard">
  <div class="cell white"></div>
  <div class="cell black"></div>
  <div class="cell white"></div>
  <div class="cell black"></div>
  <div class="cell white"></div>
  <div class="cell black"></div>
  <div class="cell white"></div>
  <div class="cell black"></div>
  
  <div class="cell black"></div>
  <div class="cell white"></div>
  <div class="cell black"></div>
  <div class="cell white"></div>
  <div class="cell black"></div>
  <div class="cell white"></div>
  <div class="cell black"></div>
  <div class="cell white"></div>
  
  <div class="cell white"></div>
  <div class="cell black"></div>
  <div class="cell white"></div>
  <div class="cell black"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Claro que le puedes asignar más de una clase de `css` en el atributo `class`. De hecho, es lo más recomendable, para que las clases de `css` que generas sean reutilizables.

Lo que no se puede hacer es asignarle más de un `id`, al igual que tampoco es nada recomendable que dos elementos de un `html` tengan el mismo `id`.

Comment: Este parece más un comentario que una respuesta

Comment: Para mí está muy bien, responde específicamente lo que OP pregunta.